# denying access for multiple users of same role in spring security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-mvc, spring-security

I've run into a such situation: my application has several roles(administrator, moderator, user). Moderator and User can edit some forms. All permisions are ok. But when I'm loggen in as a user(role User) and change an id in the url, I can simply get and edit form of another user(role User).

How to deny access and prevent such actions?

ps. version of spring and spring security is 3.1.2

update - added spring security context

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false"
        entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" access-denied-page="/403.jsp">
        <form-login login-page="/login.html"
            authentication-failure-url="/login.html?error=true"
            login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
            authentication-success-handler-ref="successHandler" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login.html" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="hasRole('adminViewPermission')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/moderator/**" access="hasRole('moderatorViewPermission')" />

        <intercept-url pattern="**/form-management"
            access="hasRole('formManagementPermission')" />

    </http>


    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService" />
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.html" />
        <beans:property name="forceHttps" value="false" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="successHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/authenticate" />
        <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="com.jack.MyYserDetailsService">
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Can you attach your `security-context.xml`?

Comment: So do you want to deny access for different users not roles?

Comment: @AleksandrM yes, I want to deny user editting of other user's form

Comment: You should correct the title of your question.

Comment: @AleksandrM changed :) ok now?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you want take into account actual domain object for your security rule. Normal SpringSecurity setup with users and roles can add security rules like this: who (athenticated user with some role) may access to some URL / method invocation. If you want to be able use enhanced rules like this: who (athenticated user with some role) may access to some URL / method invocation **and what domain objects he can use** then you need to use [ACL feature](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/domain-acls.html).

**EDIT.** But if you need **just one** security rule like this then set up ACL may be an overkill. You can try enhance your actual SpringSecurity setup by custom web security expression:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/moderator/**" access="hasRole('moderatorViewPermission') and userIsAuthor()" />
```

Where your **userIsAuthor()** method will:

- extract id of the object from the URL (I suppose something like **/moderator/item/56**)
- check if current user is an author of an item id = 56.