# spring security 3 - restrict role access to actual user

Tags: spring, spring-security, roles

in my web application i want users (role USER) to have their private page, which they can only see themselves. i also want to have a super admin (role ADMIN) which can see all private pages of all user.

So i model the urls like the following way:

```
/user/{userId}/...
```

Now apart from ADMIN only USER with userid should be able to invoke this page. Users can be dynamically added and their userid will be a generated serial number.

I started modelling it like this:

```
<http pattern="/user/**" use-expressions="true"  >
    ...
    <intercept-url pattern="/user/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_ADMIN')" />
    ... 
</http>
```

But doing so would e.g. enable USER with userid 2 to invoke `/user/1/...`

What is the proper way to do this? Can somebody give me an example?

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/14276451/1700321.

Answer (score 2):

The userId in `/user/{userId}/` is meaningful only when the user has ADMIN role. For other users, just ignore the parameter and use

```
UserDetails userDetails =
      (UserDetails)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();

if('ROLE_ADMIN' in userDetails.getAuthorities() ){
    //get user indentified by userId
}
else{
   //get current user 
}
```

to get current user related information.

Comment: Nice idea, I haven't thought about that. However, that suggests that I have to determine on business layer what roles a user have and if possible i want my business layer to stay out of this.

Comment: @flo I don't know where you put business logic, but you can validate user authorities with `userDetails.getAuthorities()` in the same place where you load user information. I updated my code to show that.