# Spring security authorization via GET parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm trying to get Spring Security to handle authorization via GET variables. All the examples I've been able to find focus pretty much entirely on role-based authorization, which doesn't really work for my application. The way the authentication/authorization process needs to work is as follows:

1. User authenticates through external system, gets a session ID.
2. User passes two GET parameters to my application, sessionId and objectId.
3. Application verifies that session is valid (already figured this part out)
4. Application verifies that the object is visible to the user (need help here)
5. Application returns object information to the user

All the examples I've seen have been demonstrating how powerfully Spring Security can check a granted authority on a URL pattern or a Java method. But I need to implement a custom check on step 4 to make sure that the user has the correct permissions in the backend (users can be granted object-specific rights, so a role approach won't work here).

I am new to Spring Security, so it could be that my thought process is just all sorts of wrong. If I am, feel free to correct me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to look at the [Pre-Authentication Scenarios](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/preauth.html) section in the documentation.  In particular, you will probably need to implement a AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter to pre-authenticate the user based on the GET parameters.

Comment: Are you saying I should do the authorization on the object in the filter as well? I'm currently just using it to ensure that the user's credentials are valid.

Comment: Well, from the sounds of it you are trying to setup a SSO, like SiteMinder.  Pre-Authentication is the way that is usually done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [ACL](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#domain-acls) feature or you can emulate the same thing via some custom code (for example via custom web security expression). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275687/denying-access-for-multiple-users-of-same-role-in-spring-security/14276451#14276451) for details.